# Get window.document from webextension popup

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a firefox extension, that opens in separate window and I need to access to window.document object of all firefox opened tabs.
I couldn't find a way to do this, since webextension api only gives readonly info about tab but not window object itself.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the pages' DOM, you need to inject Content Scripts into those pages. They are the only component that can access `document` of regular tabs.

[image: Content scripts]

If you need to do this often, you can inject content scripts via the manifest. If you only need it infrequently, consider using programmatic injection with `browser.tabs.executeScript`.

See [MDN docs on content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts).

Comment: Thank you, it helps me more , just one question. It seems impossible for content_scripts to be added in newtab or "about:debugging" or "about:addons" page in firefox. Do you know is there any way to do that?

Comment: That is correct. You cannot inject scripts at all into privileged pages. You'll need to work with that in mind.